# R:DEoptim or other optimization

Tags: r, threshold

I am a novice at optimization using R code. I wanted to minimize the AIC value of SETAR for some threshold variable such as `X(t-d)*X(t-(r+d))^p`. In package `tsDyn`, this is accomplished by placing it into the `thVar` section.

A simple example is listed below: lynx is in R package `tsDyn`

```
library(tsDyn)
library(DEoptim) 

llynx=log10(lynx)
AIC(setar(llynx,m=p1,thVar=lag(llynx,-p2)*(lag(llynx,-p3))^p4)
lower=c(2,0,1,0)
upper=c(20,20,20,10)
```

How do I minimize this in `DEoptim` or another optimization tech? I have tried several times in DEoptim (probably incorrectly) but it keeps saying non-integer. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: can you give an example of how you used DEoptim and what the result was?